# Implementing user-space network card "bus-mastering" in C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, dma

I am interested in accessing network packets via "bus-mastering" in a C++ application on Linux. I have a few questions relating to this overall topic:

1) How will I know which memory address range the "bus-mastering"-enabled Network card is writing the data to and would this be kernel or user space?

2) If #2 is "Kernel space", how could I change the card so that it writes to memory in user space?

3a) How can I access this particular user-space memory area from C++?

3b) I understand you cannot just start accessing memory areas of other processes from one application, only those explicitly "shared"- so how do I ensure the memory area written to directly by the network card is explicitly for sharing?

4) How do I know whether a network card implements "bus-mastering"?

I have come across the term `PACKET_MMAP` - is this going to be what I need?

Comment: Is it fair to say most people would understand this concept as "DMA" even if it technically isnt?

Comment: Have edited to reflect your advice- thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy

Comment: @didierc Thanks- but I am asking for practical code/advice how to actually implement this.

Comment: You could use the mmap syscall to create an in memory buffer bound to a descriptor created specifically for the situation, then use the splice syscall to zero-copy data from the mmap buffer to the socket buffer. I guess it would be interesting to use the mmap space as an allocation space for pod type objects, thus avoiding the need to copy your data there.

Comment: @didierc havent you just performed a copy when you said: "then use the splice syscall to zero-copy data from the mmap buffer to the socket buffer". I thought there was a way for the NIC to send packets directly to the user-space shared memory buffer?

Comment: The whole point of the [splice](http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice) syscall is to avoid memcopy (where possible) by having kernel structures corresponding to file, socket, etc descriptors sharing memory pages. Different virtual addresses, but same underlying physical mem pages means no need to copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mmap a region of memory, and give the address of that to the OS, the OS can lock that region (so that it doesn't become swapped out) and get the physical address of the memory.

It is not at all used for that purpose, but the code in drivers/xen/privcmd.c, in the function `mmap_mfn_range` called from `privcmd_ioctl_mmap` (indirectly, by `traverse_map`). This in turn calls `remap_area_mfn_pte_fn` from `xen_remap_domain_mfn_range`.

So, if you do something along those lines in the driver, such that the pages are locked into memory and belong to the application, you can program the physical address(es) of the `mmap`'d region into the hardware of the network driver, and get the data directly to the user-mode memory that was mmap'd by the user code.

Comment: So basically create a hard-coded address range in userland, then go in to the driver and change where the data is sent- send it to userland and then pick up the data from C++ app? What prevents another process from writing to that memory region in userland? How does this approach compare with PACKET_MMAP (http://wiki.ipxwarzone.com/index.php5?title=Linux_packet_mmap)?

Comment: `mmap` maps a region of physical memory into the space of that process to a virtual address - the address is not available to any other process, and it doesn't have to be hard-coded, it could be the result of a random number, or, better yet, let the OS pick one itself (give address NULL). I only quickly read your link, as it seems to be referring to Linux 2.4 and 2.6, which is a bit old...

Comment: Looks like the `packet_mmap` is using a similar method (without looking at the driver side of things).

Comment: One bit I dont get- how will the NIC and the C++ app know to write/retrieve from the same "user land" address range if its not hard-coded in the driver (and C++ application)?

Comment: Because you pass the address of the `mmap`'d region to the card. Using a hard coded virtual address won't help, as the virtual address isn't what the card needs, it needs the physical address (and to know that, you need both which process it is and what the virtual address is).